# Expo App crash after update on IOS 15, seems that context dispatch stop working

Tags: react-native, expo, ios15

I'm working on an app based on expo, all works fine for Ios version above 15, with IOS 15 the app working fine in emulator (expo go and standalone) but when I test it from testflight not works well. Someone experienced the same problem? Seems that context dispatch stop working, when I update the context the connected components do not trigger the update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. The app works fine in the simulator (only `expo go`), but it's not working in **TestFlight**. The error occurs when I want to navigate from my login screen to the home screen. The app stops and the crash prompt report appears.

I have created the `ios` build with traditional build and with `eas build`

Comment: Hi,
in my case a self envoking function had caused the problem. Try to test on a simulator with the very same OS versione of your device (the device used with the test flight version). To find the component you can try to disable part of your app, for example:
- disable the footer
- disable the header
- disable the router
- disable some screens 
- etc... 

In this way you can restrict the inspection so the single component responsible for the error